# Using wildcards to 'complete' remainder of filename

Tags: php

Using PHP in Wordpress I have a set of functions that currently return the number of hits for each post for each month and year and further disaggregated by type.  As all this information is currently saved, I would like to return the total hits for each post regardless of type and also disregard time. i.e. provide a running total of hits.

Current functions are:

```
    function icc_get_view_count($type,$month,$year) {
       global $post;
       if(!isset($month)||($month=='')||!isset($year)||($year=='')) {
       $month = date('m');
       $year = date('Y');
       }
       $post_type = $post->post_type;
       if($post_type == 'partners') {
$post->ID;
$current_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, "icc_views_".$type."_".$month."_".$year, true);
if(!isset($current_views) OR empty($current_views) OR !is_numeric($current_views) ) {
     $current_views = 0;
}
}

return $current_views;
}

function icc_show_views($type,$month,$year) {
   global $post;
   if(!isset($month)||($month=='')||!isset($year)||($year=='')) {
   $month = date('m');
   $year = date('Y');
   }

   $post_type = $post->post_type;
   if($post_type == 'partners') {
echo $current_views = icc_get_view_count($type,$month,$year);
   }
}
```

which is then called by:

```
   <?php icc_show_views('single', $month, $year); ?>
```

All the posts start with 'icc_views_' and then are appended with 'type', 'month' and 'year'. I have tried using glob()

```
    $current_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, glob("icc_views_*"), true);
```

to complete the filename so the type, month and year are all returned regardless but cannot seem to get this to work.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you might want to post this in the WordPress Stack: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: glob() returns an array whereas the second parameter of get_post_meta() expects a string.

Comment: PHP "glob()" doesn't work with mysql tables!  And that's what get_post_meta()" uses!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this:

1. PHP "glob()" expands filesystem (OS-level) pathnames.  I believe Wordpress "get_post_meta()" refers to custom fields stored in the *database*.  Apples and oranges.
2. A database wildcard symbol would be "%".  I don't think it can be used with "get_post_meta()" anyway.

'Hope that helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I thought maybe I should look for a more simple answer and work from the other end by getting the sum of hits from each post_id first then exclude as necessary.  So i cam up with this base upon reading other questions and answers:

```
function icc_show_total_views($hits) {
   global $post;
   $post_type = $post->post_type;
   if($post_type == 'partners') {
    echo $current_views = get_post_meta_hits($post_id);
   }
}

function get_post_meta_hits($post_id){

    global $wpdb;
    $data   =   array();
    $wpdb->query("
            SELECT sum('meta_value')
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE `post_id` = $post_id
                    ");

    foreach($wpdb->last_result as $k => $v){
        $data[$v->meta_value] =   $v->meta_value;
    };
    return $data;
}
```

But this returns the word 'Array'.  Have I missed something fundament here?

Thanks again for the feedback, very helpful